# Read New Relic json message

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, newrelic

i have few application attached to new relic. when i enter my api key and hit SEND REQUEST i get my response in json format.

`curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:<api key>' -i`

this is what the request goes. i dont know what the above code is. well i need to read the returned json message in C# and may be then deserialize the json message.

i tried this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json");

        wr.ContentType = "application/json";
        wr.Method = "GET";
        //wr.Headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "<my api key>";
        wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "<my api key>");

        using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                int x = 10;
            }
        }
```

but i get 500 error.

Comment: Please, explain what you're trying to do. Your question should be more specific... it's impossible to understand your problem if we don't know what are you trying to do and why it's failing for you.

Comment: @JotaBe i got a curl command. How do i convert it into a c# code?

the curl command is written above and below is my c# code which i tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very close to working.  You just need to change your request header a bit as shown below (and substitute your own api key).  Then, as you say you will need to deserialize the json.  I've tested this bit of code and it returned the equivalent of the curl command.

```
    WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json");
    wr.ContentType = "application/json";
    wr.Method = "GET";
    wr.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[10000];
            int n = stream.Read(bytes, 0, 9999);
            string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        }
    }
```

As you probably know, you can use our api explorer to form the http request needed to extract the data you are interested in.  Then you should be able to copy the request from api explorer to your c# code.  See the api explorer docs here:  https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/getting-started-with-new-relics-api-explorer.